# angularJs Session saved unless I refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

i have developed an angular 1.4.8 Application, my login mechanisme work great but i have one error ,is that the session seems unsaved unless I do refresh the page,
here is my code :

```
.state('dashboard', {
          url:'/dashboard',
          controller: 'HomeController',
          templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/main.html',
          resolve:{
            auth: function($q, authenticationSvc) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();                    
                if (userInfo) {
                  deferred.resolve(userInfo);
                } else {
                  deferred.reject({ authenticated: false });
                }
                return deferred.promise;
              }
          }
```

here is the controller :

```
      authenticationSvc
          .login(credentials.username, credentials.password)
          .then(
              function(response){
                sessionFactory.setData(response.token);                    
                $state.go('dashboard.home');                                         
              },
              function(error){
                $rootScope.errorLogin = "Login failed , please verify your login/password.";
                $rootScope.showLoginFailedAlert = true; 
              }
          );
```

finally , this is the sessrionFactory :

```
function sessionFactory($window, $rootScope){
  return {
    setData: function(value){
        $window.sessionStorage["pallas_token"]= value;
        $rootScope.token = value;
    },
    getData: function(){
        return $window.sessionStorage["pallas_token"]
    },
    clearData:function(){
        $window.sessionStorage.removeItem("pallas_token");
    }
  };
}
```

what I have wrong ? I am really confused.

Comment: You are saying that when you close the tab and open again the session is blank?

Comment: @RenanFerreira no I say that I must after each login I do Refresh , else the session expired and I am redirected to the login page !!

Comment: It would be great if you can share some more code.